# .NET CORE - 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'

Tags: .net-core, cors

I have implemented the CORS in .NET core API.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseCors(AllowOriginPolicy);
            

        }
```

Below is the

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: AllowOriginPolicy,
                    builder =>
                    {
                            builder.WithOrigins(_configuration.GetSection("Cors").Get<string[]>())
                                .AllowCredentials();
                        }
                    });
            });
```

Appsettings.json

```
"Cors": ["https://swaggerhub.sbintranet.net" ]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove  .AllowCredentials() from services.AddCors, and add two new options:

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy(AllowOriginPolicy, builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins(_configuration.GetSection("Cors").Get<string[]>())
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));
```

Comment: Tried but still facing the same error. I am trying to invoke api from swagger hub.